# android soft keyboard whill be covered by input filed in cordova

Tags: android, angular, cordova

when I text input field, the input field is covered by the softkeyboard in android phone. I build my app with cordova  / angular 6

I have tried the solution:

```
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="false" />
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application/activity[@android:name='MainActivity']">
    <activity android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
</edit-config>
```

but still not working...

Is any other possible way to set by cordova, not use input focus scroll? thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

We solved using two functions in JS and the plugin ionic-plugin-keyboard.

First, catch up the event in your main function:

```
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardshow', keyboardShowHandler);
window.addEventListener('native.keyboardhide', keyboardHideHandler);
```

Then, use functions to move your fields up/down (here is our code managing our custom login form as an example to modify):

```
function keyboardShowHandler(e) {       
$("#login .content a.reset-password").slideUp("slow", function () {});
$("#login .content a.sign-up").slideUp("slow", function () {});
$("#login .content a.credits").slideUp("slow", function () {});
$("#login .content a.tutorial").slideUp("slow", function () {});
}

function keyboardHideHandler(e) {       
$("#login .content a.reset-password").slideDown("slow", function () {});
$("#login .content a.sign-up").slideDown("slow", function () {});
$("#login .content a.credits").slideDown("slow", function () {});
$("#login .content a.tutorial").slideDown("slow", function () {});
}
```